# How to bind the Destroy event for a TkToplevel window?

Tags: ruby, events, tk-toolkit

I tried this, closed the window by mouse click, but never got the event:

```
top = TkToplevel.new(root)
top.bind('<Destroy>', proc {
    ...
})
```

What's wrong?

Answer (score 2):

```
top = TkToplevel.new(root)
top.protocol "WM_DELETE_WINDOW", proc { puts "It's time to say goodbye.";
                                        top.destroy }
```

https://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/51509